# Android: SplitActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using the Holo.Light Theme for the ActionBar. I'm using the splitActionBar Option via `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in my manifest. I also use a custom layout for the ActionBar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <style name="noTitle" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
       <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

 <style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
        <item name="android:height">0dip</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

The thinking behind this one is, to not "show" the top actionbar. So I basically see the "bottom" actionbar and resize the "top" actionbar to zero. This works perfectly fine, but now the problem:

If I use the app on the new devices e.g. Galaxy S4 android 4.2.2 it resizes the "top" and "bottom" actionbar to zero. How can I only resize the top actionbar to zero, so I don't see the title on the new devices.